# How to have std::function or lambda as (optional) template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Hi I was playing around with TMP and was thinking of generating of a class
that looks something like:

```
template<typename T, typename LogFunc>
class
{
```

(where LogFunc should be defaulted to "nop" function)

Idea is to have a class that defines some functionality for instances of type T, for example checks if the number is even, and also has the option to log by calling

```
void memberFunc(T& t)
{
  LogFunc(t); 
}
```

or maybe

```
void memberFunc(T& t)
{
  LogFunc lf;
  lf(t);
}
```

Can it be done? 
From reading A on SO, lambdas are kind of problematic as templ params. 
BTW if somebody cares [this](http://pastebin.com/rhCz2y1y) is what I tried but it prints out

> :(

Comment: Lambdas are not types, they can't be passed as template parameters.

Comment: You really can't just create a no-op struct to use as the default parameter? It has to be a runtime-polymorphic functor or a lambda? `struct noop { void operator() (const T&) {} };` is just too much code for you? Just because Lambdas exist doesn't mean you should forget about everything else.

Comment: there is decltype :) though idk how to use it in this case(see the link).

Comment: @NicolBolas it is not just point of default noop , it is about actually specifying the param when I want it.

Comment: Er, unless I am misunderstanding, in your pastebinned code you never actually set `log_func` to a value. You defined `lambdada`, but you only ever make use of its type, not the actual value. Why would you expect that code to show anything but `:(`?

Comment: @Rook - yeah , problem is that I would like to have a for LogFunc type that is a function that does something, not a type that is a type of function that does something.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense now. I think you are out of luck here; function wrappers of this kind cannot appear in constant expressions. There was at least one detailed explanation of why in a SO answer not so long ago, but I cannot find it now :( It is not clear to me that you gain any benefit by passing the value of the function wrapper in as a template parameter rather than as a construction argument. Emilio's solution below does just that.

Comment: Using the term *lambda* is a bit confusing. There's a distinction between a *lambda expression* and the *closure object* which it yields. The latter admits a *closure object type* (or *closure type* for short) as its type, which can in fact be used as a template parameter. This won't help you in this case though, because your `LogFunc` must be dependent on `T` or be polymorphic.

Comment: @LucDanton what do you mean by dependant on T or polymorhic?  Can you give example, for example If I have template <typename T/*...*/ what can LogFunc be?

Comment: `LogFunc(t);` does not do what you think it does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the type of a lambda is a compiler-enforced singleton; it has only one value, which is the lambda itself; furthermore, the type has a deleted constructor. So you can't pass lambdas as part of a template instantiation, even with decltype. But there's nothing stopping you from passing them as constructor arguments.

However, here we run into another problem: constructor arguments are not used to deduce a template instantiation (which is why the standard library provides utilities like make_pair and make_tuple). So we need a templatized factory function.

With all that, the solution is pretty simple:

```
template<typename T, typename LogFunc>
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(const T& t, LogFunc fn) : t_(t), lfn_(fn) {}
    //...

  private:
    T t_;
    LogFunc lfn_;
};

struct Noop {
  template<typename...A>
  void operator()(A...) { };
};

template<typename T, typename LogFunc=Noop>
Foo<T, LogFunc> make_foo(const T& t, LogFunc func=LogFunc()) {
  return Foo<T, LogFunc>(t, func);
}
```

Comment: can you provide simple use example. I cant get make_foo to work...    auto l=[] (int i){return i >0;} ;
 make_foo<int, decltype(l)>();

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: You're not supposed to supply template parameters to make_foo; it can deduce them. That's the whole point of the factory function. Example here: http://ideone.com/KqCjIJ

Comment: WOW!, that is sick. :) It even works when i put the function in the class, not just with free function... though tbh I still didnt figured out HOW it works, but there is time...  :D I guess like you said in the A we need to a way to tell the machinery what are templ args and for that we need templ factory that deduces types from inputs to itself.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: By the way, the definition of Noop is the real hack in that answer. That particular definition, as long as it keeps working, allows you to use Noop in any environment whatsoever in which you need a Noop function with `void` return (and if a function doesn't return `void`, it can't reasonably be replaced with a no-op, no? because returning something is an op :) ). So it's feasible for a library header instead of providing a specialized one for every instance. I'm still amazed it works.

Answer (score 2):

This will not answer directly, but  gives a number of hints about what you did.

The `LogFunc` parameter is a type (not an object), hence

- `LogFunc(t)` creates a temporary `LogFunc` giving `t` as parameter (you are in fact calling the `LogFunc::LogFunc(T&)` contructor).
- `LogFunc lf; lf(t);` creates a stack-living default contructed `Logfunc`, named lf, and `lf(t)` calls its `LogFunc::operator()(T&)` member function.
- `LogFunc()(t)` creates a temporary default-constructed LogFUnc and calls operator()(T&) on it.

About lambdas, they are in fact classes whose constructor takes the captured varaibles, and whose operator() takes the parameters you declare. But they exist only "internaly" to the compiler, and don't have a "name" you can refer to.

What you can do is deduce its type with a `decltype`, or with a free-function.

Typically a parametric functional class stores a frunction object, initialized at construction.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Fn>
class LogFunc
{
public:
    LogFunc(Fn f) :fn(f) {}

    template<class T>
    void memberFunc(T& t)
    { fn(t); }
private:
    Fn fn;
};

template<class Fn>
LogFunc<Fn> makeLogFunc(Fn f)
{ return LogFunc<Fn>(f); }

int main()
{
    int x=5;

    auto lf = makeLogFunc([](int& a){ std::cout << a << std::endl; });
    lf.memberFunc(x);

    return 0;
}
```

compile as "g++ -pedantic -Wall -std=c++11", and will ouptut

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are all fine, but you can also just pass in a constructor argument with a `std::function<T>`. That looks like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> void someOther(T val){
  std::cout << "used other "<<val<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T> void noop(T val){
  std::cout << "noop "<<val<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
struct A{
  A(std::function<void(T)> f =noop<T> ) : mf(f){}
  void memberFunc(T valx){
    mf(valx);
  }
  std::function<void(T)> mf;
};

int main(){
  A<int> aNoop; ;
  A<float> aSomeOther{someOther<float>} ;
  aNoop.memberFunc(5);
  aSomeOther.memberFunc(3.55);
}
```

### An alternative is to use functor classes, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T> struct OtherC{
  void operator()(T v){ std::cout <<"other "<<v<<std::endl; };
};
template <typename T> struct NoopC{
  void operator()(T){ std::cout << "noop"<<std::endl; };
};
template<typename T, template <typename X> class F = NoopC >
struct A{
  static void memberFunc(T valx){ F<T>()(valx); }
};
int main(){
  A<int> aNoop; 
  A<float,OtherC> aSomeOther ;
  aNoop.memberFunc(5);
  aSomeOther.memberFunc(3.55);
}
```